# Specialized template function with deleted "general" case fails to compile with g++ <=4.8.0 and clang++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, deleted-functions

Compiling a project with an older version of g++ (4.8.0, MinGW) I found that this code fails to compile:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() = delete;

template<>
void foo<int>(){}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that g++ doesn't even try to look for explicit specializations if it sees that the base case is deleted.

```
mitalia@mitalia:~/scratch$ /opt/mingw32-dw2/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 buggy_deleted_template.cpp 
buggy_deleted_template.cpp: In function 'int main()':
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:8:14: error: use of deleted function 'void foo() [with T = int]'
     foo<int>();
              ^
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:5:6: error: declared here
 void foo<int>(){}
      ^
mitalia@mitalia:~/scratch$ /opt/mingw32-dw2/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ --version 
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (rubenvb-4.8.0) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Instead, g++ 4.8.4 and 5.2 (on Linux) do not complain. Is this a bug in the older version of the compiler or a gray area in the standard?

---

***Addendum***

clang 3.4.1 too seems not to like it:

```
mitalia@mitalia:~/scratch$ clang++ -std=c++11 buggy_deleted_template.cpp                                                             
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:5:6: error: redefinition of 'foo'                                                                         
void foo<int>(){}
     ^
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:5:6: note: previous definition is here
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:8:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo<int>();
    ^~~~~~~~
buggy_deleted_template.cpp:2:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int]
void foo() = delete;
     ^
2 errors generated.
mitalia@mitalia:~/scratch$ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

(and *@Baum mit Augen* in the comments reports that it still doesn't work in 3.7)

Comment: For the record, clang3.7 rejects this.

Comment: I didn't know you can declare  a function as deleted. Any info on that?

Comment: @BЈовић: at C++11 §8.4.3 the standard talks about "deleted functions" in general, there's no restriction to just member functions. I actually found such possibility extremely useful as a tool to disable dangerous implicit conversions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if the following will be enlightening but I found [defect report 941: Explicit specialization of deleted function template](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#941)  with status *C++11*  that states the following **(Emphasis Mine)**:

> According to 14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 1, only non-deleted
>   function templates may be explicitly specialized. **There doesn't
>   appear to be a compelling need for this restriction, however, and it
>   could be useful to forbid use of implicitly-instantiated
>   specializations while still allowing use of explicitly-specialized
>   versions.**
>
> Proposed resolution (February, 2010):
>
> Change 14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 1 as follows:
>
> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> <del>non-deleted</del> function template
>
> class template
>
> <del>non-deleted</del> member function of a class template
>
> static data member of a class template
>
> member class of a class template
>
> member class template of a class or class template
>
> <del>non-deleted</del> member function template of a class or class
>   template
>
> can be declared...

Now the current state of the draft standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) is *14.7.3 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]:*

> 1 An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> (1.1) — function template
>
> (1.2) — class template
>
> (1.3) — variable template
>
> (1.4) — member function of a class template
>
> (1.5) — static data member of a class template
>
> (1.6) — member class of a class template
>
> (1.7) — member enumeration of a class template
>
> (1.8) — member class template of a class or class template
>
> (1.9) — member function template of a class or class template
>
> ...

So I guess:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() = delete;

template<>
void foo<int>(){}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Is C++11 standard compatible code and should be accepted.

Comment: That's exactly my use case; since the defect report was accepted (in my N3291 the "non deleted" part is missing) it looks like the committee explicitly validated such use. I'll just wait for a few more hours to see if anybody comes up with anything else before accepting your answer (meanwhile, +1).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the defect report referenced in [this g++ bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60216), fixed in 4.8.3 and 4.9.1; ironically, the fix was prompted by an ICE caused by a test case similar to mine, that the reporter though was invalid C++. :-) I guess we have a bug in clang++, then.

Comment: @MatteoItalia for clang the status of [this defect report](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) is unknown.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: well, I'd say that now it is known as "not resolved" :) I'll open a bug report ASAP.

Comment: Apparently the bug is already there... https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17537