# Deleted template function works on gcc, but not on clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am having trouble with a template specialisation of a deleted template function. The code below shows the problem boiled down to a MWE:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
inline std::string typeToString() = delete;

template<>
inline std::string typeToString<float>()
{
    return "float";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeToString<float>() << std::endl;
}
```

With `gcc 7` this compiles fine. However, with `Apple LLVM 8.0.0` I get the following error messages:

```
clang test.cpp -std=c++1z
test.cpp:8:28: error: inline declaration of 'typeToString<float>' follows non-inline definition
    inline std::string typeToString<float>()
                       ^
test.cpp:8:28: note: previous definition is here
test.cpp:15:18: error: call to deleted function 'typeToString'
std::cout << typeToString<float>() << std::endl;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:8:28: note: candidate function [with T = float] has been explicitly deleted
    inline std::string typeToString<float>()
```

Comment: Perhaps Apple LLVM 8.0.0 was written against an [older version of the C++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258249/501250) which did not permit specialization of deleted functions. Is there a newer version of this compiler that you could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug.  If you compile with clang 3.9.1 or above it will compile.  The following examples on [Golbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/MtkXd4) and [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/guqg7648tUt0TBYT) with clang 3.8.1 fail but when we change to 3.9.1 they both compile.