# Member template specialization does not compile with clang

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, std, clang++

Consider the following program:

```
struct S {
    enum E {
        e
    };
    template<E> void f() = delete;
};

template<> void S::f<S::E::e>() {}

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f<S::E::e>();
}
```

GCC 5.4.0 compiles the code, while clang 3.8.0 fails:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp 
main.cpp:10:20: error: redefinition of 'f'
template<> void S::f<S::E::e>() {
                   ^
main.cpp:8:20: note: previous definition is here
template<> void S::f<S::E::e>();
                   ^
main.cpp:14:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'f'
        s.f<S::E::e>();
        ~~^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:22: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with $0 = S::E::e]
    template<E> void f() = delete;
                     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Is clang correct and GCC wrong or is it the opposite? Note that if the `delete` specifier is removed, then clang compiles the code.

Comment: clang 3.9 compiles it.

Comment: so is it probably a bug in clang 3.8.0? it would be helpful to know what the standard says

Comment: [This paragraph of N4140 is highly relevant, I think.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#7)

Comment: the code can be simplified to [this](https://godbolt.org/g/iiEmfm), note that latest clang compiles.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256589/specialized-template-function-with-deleted-general-case-fails-to-compile-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems defect report [Explicit specialization of deleted function template](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#941) , as you can see from [here](https://godbolt.org/g/iiEmfm) the issue seems fixed in clang since 3.9.0.